# ARM Assembly - Are the instructions equivalent?

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, arm

Is "stmdb r3!, {sp,lr}" equivalent to the sequence ?

1. str sp, [r3, #-4]!
2. str lr, [r3, #-4]!

And

Is "ldmia r0!, {sp,lr}" equivalent to the sequence ?

1. ldr sp, [r0], #4
2. ldr lr, [r0], #4

Comment: how it works is described in the pseudo code next to the instruction definition in the arm documentation.  they do a pretty good job of explaining it.

Comment: How does this question relate to ARMv8?

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood the stmdb functioning. The equivalent for "stmdb r3!, {sp,lr}", would be a swapped order "lr" first followed by "sp":

- str lr, [r3, #-4]!
- str sp, [r3, #-4]!

Thanks,
Vijay

Comment: In truth it's more like `sub r3, #8; str lr, [r3]; str sp, [r3, #4]` (which would be a more efficient approach for more registers as you avoid the writeback dependency between each store). The way the ARM ARM describes load/store multiple operation is pretty clear - the lowest-numbered register is always loaded from/stored to the lowest address, etc. - it just takes a bit of thought to map that and the address fiddling appropriately to individual instructions.

Answer (score 0):

stmdb r3!, {sp,lr}

str sp, [r3, #-4]!

str lr, [r3, #-4]!

stmdb r3!, {sp,lr} - Store Multiple registers and Decrement address Before each transfer. r3 - base register and ! - write start r3 address + offcet into r3 back. 
DB - due to 4 stack type (Full Descending stack, Full Ascending stack, Empty Descending stack, Empty Ascending stack). With STM DB correspond to Full Descending stack. So sp - stack pointer and lr - link register store into memory addressed by r3 and r3 += sizeof(sp) + sizeof(ls). r3 += 8;

1. r3 point to some memory address.
2. r3 -= 8; (4 byte instruction) move r3 into lower memory address. Decrement r3.
3. Store order lr-first sp-second. Into r3-8 - lr will be stored and into r3-4 sp will be stored.
4. r3 - point to end (r3+=8);

str sp, [r3, #-4]! (pre-index variant) - store sp into r3-4 memory address and save r3-=4;

str lr, [r3, #-4]! - store lr into (r3-4)-4 and save r3-=4;

So stmdb r3!, {sp,lr} - into higher address lr situated. 
(str sp, [r3, #-4]!) + (str lr, [r3, #-4]!) lr located into higher address again.

[Introducing ARM assembly language](http://www.toves.org/books/arm/)

ldmia r0!, {sp,lr} - load multiple increment after.

Get value from memory pointed by r0 and save it into sp. Get next value from memory and save into lr.
r0 += 8;

ldr sp, [r0], #4 - load value from memory r0+4 into sp. ([r0], #4) - post-indexed variant first load and next edit r0, r0+=4.

ldr lr, [r0], #4 - load value from memory r0+4 into lr.

Into both variants value from higher memory was copied to lr.